# Use of `NF` in awk command

Tags: awk

I am trying to understand what is the difference between two command (I was expecting same result from the two):

Case-I

```
echo 'one,two,three,four,five' |awk -v FS=,  '{NF=3}1'
one two three
```

Case-II

```
echo 'one,two,three,four,five' |awk -v FS=,  -v NF=3 '{$1=$1}1'
one two three four five
```

Here is my current understanding: 
`$1=$1` is used to force awk to reconstruct and use the variables defined. I am assigning `FS` like `-v FS=","` which is in effect unlike `-v NF=3`  .

*Question: Why `NF=3` is not taking effect where as `FS=,` does.*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options:

> **-v *var*=*val***
> **--assign *var*=*val***
>
> Set the variable *var* to the value *val* before execution of the program begins.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fields:

> `NF` is a predefined variable whose value is the number of fields in the current record. `awk` automatically updates the value of `NF` each time it reads a record.

In your first program, you execute `{NF=3}` after each line is read, overwriting `NF`.

In your second program, you initially set `NF=3` via `-v`, but that value is overwritten by awk when the first line of input is read.

`FS` is different because awk never sets this variable. It will keep whatever value you give it.

Answer (score 9):

`NF` is a predefined variable whose value is the number of fields in the current record. `awk` automatically updates the value of `NF` **each time it reads a record.**

> **Remember :** whenever awk reads record/line/row, `awk` will parse fields by
>   field separator `FS` (default single space), and will recalculate fields
>   and update the same in variable `NF`.

Therefore, below one does not work.

**Why this doesn't work ?**

1. You defined `NF`,  which is before the execution of the program
2. awk read record/line/row, parsed fields, recalculated fields, so variable  `NF` overwritten.

case - 1 :

```
echo 'one,two,three,four,five' |awk -v FS=,  -v NF=3 '{$1=$1}1'
one two three four five
```

**Why this works ?**

1. awk read record/line/row, parsed fields, calculated fields, `NF` will be 5
2. you have overwritten variable `NF`

case -2 :

```
echo 'one,two,three,four,five' |awk -v FS=,  '{   NF=3  }1'
one two three
                                                  ^
                                        Because you have overwritten variable



$ echo 'one,two,three,four,five' |awk -v FS=,  '{print "Before:"NF;  NF=3; print "After:"NF}1'
Before:5
After:3
one two three
```