# Retrieving the patch name from yum command history using shell command

Tags: linux, shell, awk, yum

I am using the command to get the list of patches:

```
sudo yum --setopt=history_list_view=commands history list all
```

*The output:*

```
ID | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered

13 | remove wget              | 2018-10-16 08:56 | Erase          |    2
12 | install sssd-1.12.4-47.e | 2018-10-16 03:09 | Update         |    4 ss
11 | install unzip-6.0-2.el6_ | 2018-10-15 09:27 | Update         |    1
10 | install sqlite-3.6.20-1. | 2018-10-15 09:26 | Update         |    1
 9 | install pam-1.1.1-20.el6 | 2018-10-15 09:22 | Update         |    1
 8 | install libxml2-python-2 | 2018-10-15 09:20 | Update         |    2
 7 | install curl.x86_64      | 2018-10-15 08:56 | Update         |    2
 6 | install dhclient.x86_64  | 2018-10-15 08:55 | Update         |    2
 5 | install openssh.x86_64   | 2018-10-15 08:50 | Update         |    3
 4 | install samba-winbind-3. | 2018-10-15 04:59 | Update         |    4
 3 | install zsh-html.x86_64  | 2018-10-12 06:57 | Install        |    1
 2 | install samba            | 2017-01-05 03:17 | I, U           |    5
 1 | install wget             | 2017-01-05 03:08 | Update         |    1
```

How can I process this and get the patch name only from the command line column?

Comment: Is that text in your question the sample input or the expected output? Whichever one it is add the missing other one too so we can help you. Also add whatever code you have tried yourself to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get *the package name only* by using [**`awk`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) such way:

```
sudo yum --setopt=history_list_view=commands history list all | awk -F '|' 'NR>2{print $2}' | awk 'NF{print $2}'
```

The first awk expression splits every string by `|`-character and gives you the second column (except for the first two lines `NR>2` which describe the header of the table). The second awk expression splits second column by space-character and gives you a package name, along the way filtering empty lines ([more info about NF in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216786/use-of-nf-in-awk-command)).

The output will be like:

```
curl.x86_64
dhclient.x86_64
openssh.x86_64
zsh-html.x86_64
samba
wget
```

If you need some filtering e.g. by *`Action`*-field, the additional `grep` is needed firstly.