# How to rename files in a folder with specific conditions?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

```
S_1004_DKDL220006264-1A_HLGLFDSX3_L4_cleaned_1_fastqc.html
S_1004_DKDL220006264-1A_HLGLFDSX3_L4_cleaned_1_fastqc.zip
S_1004_DKDL220006264-1A_HLGLFDSX3_L4_cleaned_2_fastqc.html
S_1004_DKDL220006264-1A_HLGLFDSX3_L4_cleaned_2_fastqc.zip
S_1006_DKDL220006298-1A_HKFTLDSX3_L1_cleaned_1_fastqc.html
S_1006_DKDL220006298-1A_HKFTLDSX3_L1_cleaned_1_fastqc.zip
S_1006_DKDL220006298-1A_HKFTLDSX3_L1_cleaned_2_fastqc.html
```

above are the name of the files in a folder.
I want to remove between second `_` from right and second `_` from left. So that the output looks like

```
S_1004__1_fastqc.html
S_1004__1_fastqc.zip
S_1004__2_fastqc.html
S_1004__2_fastqc.zip
S_1006__1_fastqc.html
S_1006__1_fastqc.zip
S_1006__2_fastqc.html
```

How do I do this using bash?

I tried the following code:

```
for file in *.html *.zip; do
  new_name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/_[^_]*_/_/')
  mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

but it did not work the way I want.

Comment: Is it possible to use `awk` also?

Comment: yes ofcourse @mandy8055

Comment: Your `.fq.gz` example seems to break the stated rules.

Comment: You did not specify, what OS you are running. Perhaps you have (or can install [rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

Comment: @mandy8055: You are right, and I wonder why the OP removed the _ubuntu_ tag, which is relevant to this question.

Comment: I have added but some one removed the tag... oopssss...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `sed` for this (but see at the end for an explanation why your attempt fails, and for a working `sed` command).

With a recent enough `bash` (at least 3.0 for `[[ string =~ regexp ]]` and `BASH_REMATCH`):

```
for f in *.html *.zip; do
  [[ "$f" =~ ^(([^_]*_){2}).+((_[^_]*){2})$ ]] && mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

With an older bash, if your filenames do not contain newline characters:

```
for f in *.html *.zip; do
  set -f; IFS=_ read -ra a <<< "$f"; set +f; n="${#a[@]}"
  (( n > 4 )) && mv "$f" "${a[0]}_${a[1]}__${a[n-2]}_${a[n-1]}"
done
```

Note: `set -f; ...; set +f` to temporarily suppress pathname expansion because your file names could contain glob operators (`*`, `?`, `[...]`).

The reason why your attempt fails is that `sed` attempts to match regular expressions from left to right (and is greedy). In `sed 's/_[^_]*_/_/'` the leftmost match is thus substituted. If the file name is `S_1004_DKDL220006264-1A_HLGLFDSX3_L4_cleaned_1_fastqc.html`, the matched part is `_1004_` (leftmost) and the result is `S_DKDL220006264-1A_HLGLFDSX3_L4_cleaned_1_fastqc.html`.

If you really want to use `sed` for this you could try:

```
sed 's/^\([^_]*_[^_]*_\).\+\(_[^_]*_[^_]*\)$/\1\2/'
```

Comment: I believe `IFS=_ read -ra a <<<"$f"` would work with any legal name

Comment: Nope: if a file name contains newlines this would fail too.

Comment: oops. true. okay: `IFS=_ a=($f)`

Comment: Yes, excellent, I edit my answer to use that.

Comment: If `set -f` is in effect globally (I know some people who always do that in their shell programs) then `set -f; ...; set +f` will turn if off.  Also `IFS=_ a=( $f );` always leaves `$IFS` with the value `_`, which may cause unpleasant surprises elsewhere if this code is used in a larger program.

Comment: `IFS=_ a=( $f );`  is two variable assignments, not setting `IFS` for a command. That means that the value of `IFS` is changed afterwards.  Compare the outputs of `( IFS=_ :; declare -p IFS )` (where `IFS` is set just for the `:` command) and `( IFS=_ a=( $f ); declare -p IFS )`  (where  `IFS` and `a` are set at the same time).

Comment: Your point about `set -f` is correct.  Sorry for suggesting that the code is broken in this respect.  The unconditional "set A; do B; unset A" pattern sets off alarm bells for me because I've seen to much broken code that uses it.  I try to avoid it even when it is safe because  there is a danger that the code may be copied to a place where "A" may be set already.

Comment: Oops, you're right, about `IFS`, `a=( $f )` is not a command and the `IFS` assignment is persistent. Let me fix that.

Comment: There is a problem with `ifs="$IFS"; IFS=... ; IFS="$ifs";`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #49 (OIFS="$IFS"; ...; IFS="$OIFS")](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#OIFS.3D.22.24IFS.22.3B_.2BICY.3B_IFS.3D.22.24OIFS.22) and [Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264926/264812).

Comment: @pjh You're right, this is a dirty hack that may lead to unexpected results in several special cases. I replaced this with a `read` (with the drawback that it would not work if filenames contain newline characters). Anyway, if the OP's bash is older than 3.0 they should seriously consider updating. Even Apple used to ship 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

The new file name can be calculated using just the built-in string manipulation features in POSIX shell.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/sh -

for file in *_*_*_*_*.*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue

    suffix=${file##*.}
    [ "$suffix" = zip ] || [ "$suffix" = html ] || continue

    base=${file%.*}
    tmp=${base#*_*_}
    start=${base%"$tmp"}
    tmp=${base%_*_*}
    end=${base#"$tmp"}

    newfile=${start}${end}.${suffix}

    echo mv -v -n -- "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

- I (lightly) tested this with both `bash` and `dash` (the most common shells referenced by `/bin/sh`).
- `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` skips the current match if it is not a regular file.  That may be because it is some other file type (e.g. a directory or fifo) or because no files matched the pattern (so `$file` has the literal value `*_*_*_*_*.*`).
- See the [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) section of the POSIX [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) document for an explanation of `${file##*.}`, `${file*.*}`, and other string manipulations.
- Remove the `echo` if you are happy that the code will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try using awk instead of sed

```
for file in *.html *.zip; do
  new_name=$(echo "$file" | awk -F"_" '{print $1"_"$2"_"$NF}')
  mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're looking for an `awk` script for achieving the above solution. I would set the field separtor as `_` and then print the desired fields (first, second, and last but second and last fields) first and second and last separated by `_` and last but second separated by `__`.[*`NF`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47217353/19090048) being the predefined variable.

Here is the sample:

```bash
files=("All_files")

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  new_name=$(echo "$file" | awk -F '_' '{print $1 "_" $2 "__" $(NF-1) "_" $NF}')
  echo "$file -> $new_name"
  # mv "$file" "$new_name" # uncomment to rename them actually
done
```

[Script demo](https://replit.com/@msankrit/MintcreamCorruptInterface#main.sh)

---

#### Alternative Solution(using `perl`):

```bash
files=("All_files")
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  new_name=$(echo "$file" | perl -pe 's/(S_\d+)_.*_.*_(.*_.*)/\1__\2/')
  # currently the regex used with perl can accept any character.
  # If you require only word characters(i.e. [A-Za-z0-9_]), replace .* with \w*
  echo "Renaming: $file -> $new_name"
  # mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

[Script demo](https://replit.com/@msankrit/CompassionateYummyScripts#main.sh)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F_ '
        NF>=4{
           new=$1 FS $2 FS FS $(NF-1) FS $NF 
           print |"mv \47" $0 "\47 \47" new "\47"
        }
 ' < <(find files/ -type f)

$ find files/
files/
files/S_1006__1_fastqc.html
files/S_1004__2_fastqc.html
files/S_1006__2_fastqc.html
files/S_1006__1_fastqc.zip
files/S_1004__1_fastqc.zip
files/S_1004__2_fastqc.zip
files/S_1004__1_fastqc.html
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to give a try to a Perl One-liner:

```
perl -pe '{s/(^.+_\d+_).+(_\d_fastqc.+)/\1\2/}' file
```

`-e`: allows you to enter the program on the command line.

`-p`: assumes a loop around program like: while (<>) { ... }. It will also print the line so print statement is not necessary (compare it to -n below).

`-n`: assumes a while loop while (<>) { ... }. But it does not print the line unless you explicitly print it. This is not part of the program, but I am putting here for comparison to -p. If you wrote the same one-liner using -n. Your program would look like this:

`perl -ne '{$_ =~ s/(^.+_\d+_).+(_\d_fastqc.+)/\1\2/; print $_}' file`.

`$_`: this is Perl's default variable. In fact you can omit it and write the same thing as:

`perl -pe '{s/(^.+_\d+_).+(_\d_fastqc.+)/\1\2/}' file`

`s///`: this is Perl's substitution operator. For example, `s/old/new/ #Replaces old with new.`

The rest is regular expression (I am sure you can write this part in many different ways. Below is one way to do it):

`s/(^.+_\d+_).+(_\d_fastqc.+)/\1\2/`: this will match every line.

`(^.+_\d+_)`: captures from beginning of line to until the end of second underscore. It's captured by \1.

`(_\d_fastqc.+)`: matches anything right of second underscore from the left. Captured by \2.

`\1` captures the content of the first `()` set, and `\2` captures the content of the second set of `()`.

The best way to figure out what they do is to run only with \1 or \2.

In short: You are replacing entire line only with the captured parts of the line as a result non-capture text is deleted

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it